# Orange armored lizardman from old kids' TV show

Tags: story-identification, tv, toys

I used to have this toy of an armored orange lizard- or dragonman with red eyes as a kid, I didn't even know where he was from, but it was one of my favorite toys cause I just loved his design. It was a plastic action figure and came with either a sword or an axe and a blue cape.

Then I remember coming across the character one time while zapping through channels on the TV and got ecstatic to see him, now as an adult I'm trying to find what franchise this was, but I've been all out of luck so far.

It must have been early 2000's or late 90's, it had a medieval setting and it was live action. It could have been a movie, but I think it was a TV show.

It could also maybe be local to Scandinavia for all I know, as I live in Norway and my parents bought me the toy here, and I remember we were in Sweden when I came across this on TV, and I can't remember if it was dubbed or not.

Comment: land of the lost? i am going on parody of tv show with the great will farrel.

Comment: @releseabe:  The Sleestak from "Land of the Lost" were all green, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Just to be clear, was he poseable? What points of articulation? Did he come with a base to stand on?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yeah it was poseable, like an action figure; arms, legs elbows, knees and the head could be turned if I remember correctly, don't recall any base to stand on, but my memory on the details is sadly a bit hazy I'm afraid.

Comment: Any guess on what channel you saw it on. Was it one of the public channels or something like Nickelodeon?

Comment: @Bjorn Eriksson: It was a swedish channel that showed kid shows in the morning then transitioned into regular tv programming at 11:00 or so I think, could it have been Kanal 5? Sorry, wish I knew more specifically, but my memory of it all isn't very good, that's why it's been so hard to try and find it.

Comment: Perhaps Saurod from Masters of the Universe?  - he's a lizard covered in orange armour, and masters of the universe toys were widely available - the live action show would have been the masters of the universe movie from 1987